# How to draw a cube with coordinate system(s) in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to draw a cube in perspective with coordinate system and arrows for the definition of the Cauchy stress tensor in continuum mechanics. It's supposed to look like this:

[image: Cube for definition of stresses]

The example is drawn isometrically. I'd rather have it drawn in perspective.

Hope you guys can help me. Thanks!

Sincerely,
Chris

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Have you tried something?

Comment: Look up "three point perspective drawing" in the manual.

Comment: I tried the following example from another discussion here, but I didn't manage to get the arrows and the coordinate system. [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12069/220644)

Comment: If you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of what you can achieve with the `perspective` and the `3d` libraries.
To change the perspective, just change the angles in the `3d view` key.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{perspective}
    \usetikzlibrary{3d}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        3d view = {15}{15}
    ]
    
        \draw[-{Latex[scale = 0.7]}] (-4, -4, 0) -- (-3, -4, 0)
            node[below] {\footnotesize$x$};
        \draw[-{Latex[scale = 0.7]}] (-4, -4, 0) -- (-4, -3, 0)
            node[right] {\footnotesize$y$};
        \draw[-{Latex[scale = 0.7]}] (-4, -4, 0) -- (-4, -4, 1)
            node[above] {\footnotesize$z$};

        \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y = -2]
        
            \draw[
                fill = lightgray
            ] (-2, -2) rectangle (2, 2);
            
            \draw[-Latex] (-1.75, 0) -- (1.75, 0)
                node[below left] {$\sigma_{xy}$};
            \draw[-Latex] (0, -1.75) -- (0, 1.75)
                node[below left] {$\sigma_{zy}$};
        
        \end{scope}     
    
        \draw[Latex-] (0, -2, 0) -- (0, -3.5, 0)
            node[left] {$\sigma_{yy}$};
    
        \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x = 2]
    
            \draw[
                fill = lightgray
            ] (-2, -2) rectangle (2, 2);
            
            \draw[-Latex] (1.75, 0) -- (-1.75, 0)
                node[below right] {$\sigma_{yx}$};
            \draw[-Latex] (0, -1.75) -- (0, 1.75)
                node[below right] {$\sigma_{zx}$};
    
        \end{scope} 

        \draw[Latex-] (2, 0, 0) -- (3.5, 0, 0)
            node[right] {$\sigma_{xx}$};

        \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z = 2]

            \draw[
                fill = lightgray
            ] (-2, -2) rectangle (2, 2);

            \draw[-Latex] (-1.75, 0) -- (1.75, 0)
                node[above]{$\sigma_{xz}$};
            \draw[-Latex] (0, 1.75) -- (0, -1.75)
                node[above left]{$\sigma_{yz}$};

        \end{scope} 

        \draw[Latex-] (0, 0, 2) -- (0, 0, 3.5)
            node[above] {$\sigma_{zz}$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

Then, you can look at the [TikZ documentation](https://ctan.crest.fr/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) to adapt it to specific needs.

Comment: Thank you very much! One more problem: Can you tell me how to install the library "perspective"? It seems I have not installed it, as it can't be found.

Comment: @ChrisMH It's one of the standard libraries of TikZ, so you probably need to update Pgf/TikZ. (It was added March 2019.)