Recreate a Schematic of a Photonic Integrated Circuit (PIC) Using TikZ
The circuit includes components like an optical waveguide, optical fiber, optical ring resonator, photodiode, optical modulator, and photonic crystal. I would like to create the diagram without annotations or arrows—just the shapes representing the components.
I previously received your help on a similar design, and I tried to adapt the code they provided for my current schematic. However, I’m having trouble replicating the layout and level of detail.

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, calc, 3d}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    % Define colors
    \definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{2E7CAA}
    \definecolor{myred}{HTML}{E72B22}
    \definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{5DA429}
    \definecolor{mypurple}{HTML}{C29DE5}
    \definecolor{mygray}{HTML}{D1D6D9}
    
    % Optical fiber
    \draw[fill=mygray] (0,0) rectangle (0.8,0.4);
    \draw[fill=white] (0.3,0.1) rectangle (0.5,0.3);
    
    % Optical waveguide (horizontal)
    \draw[fill=myblue] (0.8,0.15) rectangle (5,0.25);
    
    % Laser
    \draw[fill=myred] (5,0.25) rectangle (6,0.75);
    
    % Optical ring resonator
    \draw[thick,fill=mygreen] (3,1.2) circle (0.5);
    
    % Photonic crystal
    \draw[fill=mypurple] (1,1.5) rectangle (2,2);
    
    % Photodiode
    \draw[fill=mygreen] (0.5,2) rectangle (1.5,2.5);
    
    % Optical modulator
    \draw[fill=myblue] (4.5,1) rectangle (5.5,1.5);
    
    % Input coupler (approximation as a square)
    \draw[fill=myred] (4.5,2) rectangle (5.2,2.7);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I’ve been unable to replicate the precise layout and positioning of the components.
Could you provide any guidance on how to draw smooth paths for the waveguides and connections between components?
I’d appreciate any help or advice on how to take this diagram closer to the original!


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Do you have access to EDA tools? If so, why don’t you create such images there AND include it via graphicx? // I get the impression you misuse this community to outsource detailed work.

No I don't have access to EDA tools. I am a final-year master's student currently working on my thesis and seeking assistance with LaTeX. I am relatively new to LaTeX and need help reproducing a specific design for my thesis. Your guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you. // Yesterday you had a similar question, with a nice answer using \pic elements. If you adopt it, you can, right away, create all cuboid structures. That would be a much better starting point for your question: how to add the cylinder (jack) and the circular structures.

@MS-SPO what are eda tools?

how many of these pictures do you have to draw and how complicated do they get? unless the answer is very few and fairly simple, you would be far better investing your efforts in learning an alternative way to draw them. there are open source programmes you can use to draw 3d images. tikz is great for schematics, but it is bad for both realism and 3d generally. of course, it can be done, but that doesn't make it a sensible approach.

@cfr: EDA means Electronic Design Automation. Synonyms are also CAD tools, layout tools and often any other specialized tool name, like Verilog (digital design synthesis). Common exaggerated conotation is „we do glorious gorgeous complicated electronics and semiconductor stuff, your unworthiness“ … Well, more Hybris than substance ;)

@MS-SPO :-), thanks. translation to CAD makes sense. I didn't realise EDA meant the same.

@cfr … slang is everywhere (a la John Paul Young) …

In the starting post one can see many cuboids of the following kind (similar to the other thread):

So it's obvious that one should make a template with pic for this.
The rest is a Sisyphean task...
Hint 1:
In the following MWE, the 3d-library is not absolutely necessary.
But its syntax
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=<value>]
....
\end{scope}

can make the whole thing a little clearer maybe, at some places.
Now then, for the fun of drawing with TikZ...

\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} 
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta, bending}

\definecolor{mycyan}{HTML}{9CCFE9}
\definecolor{mydarkcyan}{HTML}{415D69}
\definecolor{mylightgray}{HTML}{9B9690}
\definecolor{mysilver}{HTML}{C0C0C0}
\definecolor{myred}{HTML}{F35F5D}
\definecolor{mydarkred}{HTML}{681F19}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{8CDF8D}
\definecolor{mydarkgreen}{HTML}{306132}
\definecolor{myviolet}{HTML}{BAB8E7}
\definecolor{mydarkviolet}{HTML}{5B5882}
\definecolor{mydarkbrown}{HTML}{3F352E}

\pgfmathsetmacro\wx{42}
\pgfmathsetmacro\wy{180-38}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\s{sqrt(5)*0.5cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
y={(\wy:\s)},x={(\wx:\s)}, z={(0cm,0.35cm)},
>={Triangle[length=0pt 3*3,width=0pt 6]},
%% Cuboid ===========================
pics/cuboid/.style n args={6}{
code={%%
\coordinate(A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate(B1) at (#1,0);
\coordinate(C1) at (#1,#2);
\coordinate(D1) at (0,#2);
\coordinate(A2) at (0,0,#3);
\coordinate(B2) at (#1,0,#3);
\coordinate(C2) at (#1,#2,#3);
\coordinate(D2) at (0,#2,#3);
% Cuboid draw
\path[draw=none, fill=none] (A1) -- (B1) -- (C1)  -- (D1) -- cycle;
\path[draw=none, fill=#4,
local bounding box=#6-box,% Cuboid coordinates 1/5
] (A2) -- (B2) coordinate[pos=0.5, label=](#6-Start) % Cuboid coordinates 2/5
  -- (C2)  -- (D2) coordinate[pos=0.5, label=](#6-End)% Cuboid coordinates 3/5
    -- cycle;
\fill[#5] (A1) -- (A2) -- (D2) -- (D1) --cycle;
\fill[#5] (A1) -- (B1) -- (B2) -- (A2) --cycle;
%
\coordinate[label=](#6-start) at (0,0.5*#2,#3);% Cuboid coordinates 4/5
\coordinate[label=](#6-end) at (#1,0.5*#2,#3);% Cuboid coordinates 5/5
% ===================================
% ===================================
% Show Coordinates and Name - comment out! =======
\draw[dashdotted] (#6-start) -- (#6-end) node[midway, above]{#6};% Test
\draw[dotted] (#6-Start) -- (#6-End) node[]{};% Test
%% ===================================
},%%
},% ==================
]
% Motherboard ==================
\draw[] (0,0,-0.5) pic{cuboid={12}{10}{0.5}{mylightgray}{mydarkbrown}{MB}};
%\draw[] (MB-start) -- (MB-end); % Test
% ==========================

% Optical Ring =================
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
\path[draw=none, fill=mydarkcyan, even odd rule]
  (5.5,6.5) circle[radius=1] 
  (5.5,6.5) circle[radius=0.575]; 
\end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0.5]
\path[draw=none, fill=mycyan, even odd rule, local bounding box=OR-box]
  (5.5,6.5) circle[radius=1] 
  (5.5,6.5) circle[radius=0.575]; 
%\node at (OR.north){OR}; % test
\end{scope}
%% ======================

% Connection 2
\draw[] (3.5,4.25,0) pic{cuboid={0.5}{5}{0.5}{mycyan}{mydarkcyan}{C2}};
% Photonic Crystal
\draw[] (3,2.75,0) pic{cuboid={1.5}{1.5}{0.5}{myviolet}{mydarkviolet}{PC}};
% Connection 1
\draw[] (2,3.25,0) pic{cuboid={1}{0.5}{0.5}{mycyan}{mydarkcyan}{C1}};
% Photo Diode 1
\draw[] (1,2.5,0) pic{cuboid={1}{2}{0.5}{mygreen}{mydarkgreen}{PD1}};

% Photo Diode 2
\draw[] (6.25,8,0) pic{cuboid={2}{1}{0.5}{mygreen}{mydarkgreen}{PD2}};
% Connection 3
\draw[] (7,3,0) pic{cuboid={0.5}{5}{0.5}{mycyan}{mydarkcyan}{C3}};
% Connection 4
\draw[] (6,2.5,0) pic{cuboid={1.5}{0.5}{0.5}{mycyan}{mydarkcyan}{C4}};
% Laser
\draw[] (9,9,0) pic{cuboid={1.5}{1.5}{0.5}{myred}{mydarkred}{L}};


% ===================================
% Optical Modulator ========================
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\coordinate[label=Al1](Al1) at (9.5,4.5,0);
\coordinate[label=Bl1](Bl1) at (9,5.5,0);
\coordinate[label=Cl1](Cl1) at (9,7,0);
\coordinate[label=Dl1](Dl1) at (9.5,7.5,0); 
\coordinate[label=El1](El1) at (9.5,8.5,0); 
\coordinate[label=Fl1](Fl1) at (9,9,0); 
\coordinate[label=Fr1](Fr1) at (10.5,9,0);
\coordinate[label=Er1](Er1) at (10,8.5,0);
\coordinate[label=Dr1](Dr1) at (10,7.5,0); 
\coordinate[label=Cr1](Cr1) at (10.5,7,0); 
\coordinate[label=Br1](Br1) at (10.5,5.5,0); 
\coordinate[label=Ar1](Ar1) at (10,4.5,0);
%
\coordinate[label=P1](P1) at (9.75,4.75,0);
\coordinate[label=Ql1](Ql1) at (9.5,5.25,0);
\coordinate[label=Rl1](Rl1) at (9.5,6.75,0); 
\coordinate[label=S1](S1) at (9.75,7.25,0); 
\coordinate[label=Pr1](Pr1) at (10,6.75,0);
\coordinate[label=Qr1](Qr1) at (10,5.25,0); 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\coordinate[label=Al2](Al2) at (9.5,4.5,0.5);
\coordinate[label=Bl2](Bl2) at (9,5.5,0.5);
\coordinate[label=Cl2](Cl2) at (9,7,0.5);
\coordinate[label=Dl2](Dl2) at (9.5,7.5,0.5); 
\coordinate[label=El2](El2) at (9.5,8.5,0.5); 
\coordinate[label=Fl2](Fl2) at (9,9,0.5); 
\coordinate[label=Fr2](Fr2) at (10.5,9,0.5);
\coordinate[label=Er2](Er2) at (10,8.5,0.5);
\coordinate[label=Dr2](Dr2) at (10,7.5,0.5); 
\coordinate[label=Cr2](Cr2) at (10.5,7,0.5); 
\coordinate[label=Br2](Br2) at (10.5,5.5,0.5); 
\coordinate[label=Ar2](Ar2) at (10,4.5,0.5);
%
\coordinate[label=P2](P2) at (9.75,4.75,0.5);
\coordinate[label=Ql2](Ql2) at (9.5,5.25,0.5);
\coordinate[label=Rl2](Rl2) at (9.5,6.75,0.5); 
\coordinate[label=S2](S2) at (9.75,7.25,0.5); 
\coordinate[label=Pr2](Pr2) at (10,6.75,0.5);
\coordinate[label=Qr2](Qr2) at (10,5.25,0.5); 
\end{scope}
%
% Inner Fill Areas
%\fill[mydarkcyan] (Al1) -- (Ar1) -- (Ar2) -- (Al2) --cycle;
\fill[mydarkcyan] (Al1) -- (Bl1) -- (Bl2) -- (Al2) --cycle;
\fill[mydarkcyan] (Bl1) -- (Cl1) -- (Cl2) -- (Bl2) --cycle;
\fill[mydarkcyan] (Dl1) -- (El1) -- (El2) -- (Dl2) --cycle;
\fill[mydarkcyan] (El1) -- (Fl1) -- (Fl2) -- (El2) --cycle;
%
\fill[mydarkcyan] (P1) -- (Qr1) -- (Qr2) -- (P2) --cycle;
\fill[mydarkcyan] (Qr1) -- (Pr1) -- (Pr2) -- (Qr2) --cycle;
\fill[mydarkcyan] (Pr1) -- (S1) -- (S2) -- (Pr2) --cycle;
%
% Lower Area 
\path[fill=none, draw=none, even odd rule
]  (Al1) -- (Bl1) -- (Cl1) -- (Dl1) -- (El1) -- (Fl1) 
  -- (Fr1) -- (Er1) -- (Dr1) -- (Cr1) -- (Br1) --  (Ar1) --cycle
%
(P1) -- (Ql1) -- (Rl1) -- (S1) -- (Pr1)  -- (Qr1) --cycle;
%
% Upper Area
\path[fill=mycyan, draw=none, even odd rule
]  (Al2) -- (Bl2) -- (Cl2) -- (Dl2) -- (El2) -- (Fl2) 
  -- (Fr2) -- (Er2) -- (Dr2) -- (Cr2) -- (Br2) --  (Ar2) --cycle
%
(P2) -- (Ql2) -- (Rl2) -- (S2) -- (Pr2)  -- (Qr2) --cycle;
% ===================================

% Connection 5
\draw[] (9.5,3,0) pic{cuboid={0.5}{1.5}{0.5}{mycyan}{mydarkcyan}{C5}};
% Connection 6
\draw[] (8.5,2.5,0) pic{cuboid={1.5}{0.5}{0.5}{mycyan}{mydarkcyan}{C6}};


% =========================
%% Optical Waveguide
\draw[] (1.25,0.5,0) pic{cuboid={10}{1}{0.75}{mycyan}{mydarkcyan}{OWG}};
% =============================
% Optical Waveguide Entry ==================
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
\path[draw=none] (0.25,0.5) coordinate(P1) -- (1.25,0.5) coordinate(Q1) 
-- (1.25,1.5) coordinate(R1) -- (0.25,1.5) coordinate(S1) --cycle;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=1.75]
\path[draw=none] (0.25,0.5) coordinate(P2) -- (0.25,1.5) coordinate(S2);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0.75]
\path[draw=none](1.25,0.5) coordinate(Q2) -- (1.25,1.5) coordinate(R2);
\end{scope}

%\draw[mydarkcyan] (P2) -- (Q2) -- (R2) -- (S2);
\fill[mydarkcyan] (P1) -- (P2) -- (S2) -- (S1);
\fill[mydarkcyan] (P1) -- (Q1) -- (Q2) -- (P2) --cycle;
\fill[mycyan] (P2) -- (Q2) -- (R2) -- (S2) --cycle;

\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
% Cylinder at Coupler entry
\node[cylinder, draw, rotate=\wx+180, 
anchor=west, 
minimum height=17mm, minimum width=8mm,
cylinder uses custom fill, 
cylinder end fill = black,
cylinder body fill = mysilver,
alias=OF,
] (cyl) at (0.5,1.125) {};
\end{scope}
% =============================
% =============================

% Annotations
\matrix[matrix of nodes, anchor=north west, xshift=10mm, yshift=-40mm,
row sep=7ex, nodes={text width=30mm, align=center}, 
font=\Large, draw=none,
](mr) at (MB-box.north east) {
Input coupler \\ 
Optical modulator \\ 
Oprical waveguide \\
Couplers \\
Photonic crystal \\
};

\matrix[matrix of nodes, anchor=north east, xshift=-10mm, yshift=-40mm,
row sep=7ex, nodes={text width=30mm, align=center}, 
font=\Large, draw=none,
](ml) at (MB-box.north west) {
Laser \\ 
{Optical ring \\ resonator} \\
Photo diode \\
Optical fiber \\
};

% 1r
\path[draw=none] (Er2) -- (Fr2) coordinate[pos=0.5, label=](IC1); 
\draw[<-, very thick] (IC1) -| ([yshift=40mm]MB-box.east) |- (mr-1-1.west); 

% 2r
\path[draw=none] (Ar2) -- (Br2) coordinate[pos=0.5, label=](OM1); 
\draw[<-, very thick] (OM1) -| ([yshift=20mm]MB-box.east) |- (mr-2-1.west); 


% 3r & 4r
\path[draw=none] (OWG-start) -- (OWG-end) 
   coordinate[pos=0.9, label=](OWG1)
      coordinate[pos=0.8, label=](OWG2)
           coordinate[pos=0.6, label=](OWG3);

\draw[<-, very thick] (OWG1) -| (MB-box.east) |- (mr-3-1.west); 
\draw[<-, very thick] (OWG2) -| ([xshift=-5mm]MB-box.east) |- ([yshift=1mm]mr-4-1.west); 
\draw[<-, very thick] (OWG3)
   -| ([xshift=-10mm,yshift=-15mm]MB-box.east) 
        |- ([yshift=-1mm]mr-4-1.west); 

% 5r
\path[draw=none] (PC-box.south) -- (PC-box.east) coordinate[pos=0.5, label=](PC1); 
\draw[<-, very thick, shorten <=3mm] (PC1) -| ([xshift=-40, yshift=-40mm]MB-box.east) |- (mr-5-1.west); 


% 1l 
\path[draw=none] (L-box.west) -- (L-box.north) coordinate[pos=0.5, label=](L1); 
\draw[<-, very thick] ([xshift=-3mm]L1) -| ([xshift=0mm, yshift=40mm]MB-box.west) |- (ml-1-1.east); 

% 2l 
\draw[<-, very thick, shorten <=3mm] ([xshift=3mm]OR-box.west) |-  ([yshift=20mm]MB-box.west)  |- (ml-2-1.east); 

% 3l-1 
\draw[<-, very thick, shorten <=-5mm] ([xshift=-5mm]PD1-box.south) -|  ([xshift=5mm, yshift=-20mm]MB-box.west)  |- ([yshift=-1mm]ml-3-1.east); 

% 3l-2 
\draw[<-, very thick, shorten <=-5mm] ([yshift=-5mm, xshift=-8mm]PD2-box.north) -|  ([xshift=5mm, yshift=30mm]MB-box.west)  |- ([yshift=1mm]ml-3-1.east); 

% 5l
\draw[<-, very thick, shorten <=3mm, ] (cyl) -|  ([yshift=-50mm]MB-box.west)  |- (ml-4-1.east); 


% Red Arrows ====================
% C2
\path[draw=none] (C2-Start) -- (C2-End) coordinate[pos=0.4, label=](AC2);
\draw[->, very thick, red] (AC2) -- ($(AC2)!10mm!(C2-Start)$);

% C3
\path[draw=none] (C3-Start) -- (C3-End) 
  coordinate[pos=-0.075, label=](AC3-1)
     coordinate[pos=0.5, label=](AC3-2)
       coordinate[pos=0.8, label=](AC3-3);
\draw[->, very thick, red] (AC3-1) -- ($(AC3-1)!10mm!(C3-Start)$);
\draw[->, very thick, red] (AC3-2) -- ($(AC3-2)!10mm!(C3-End)$);
\draw[->, very thick, red] (AC3-3) -- ($(AC3-3)!10mm!(C3-End)$);

% C5
\path[draw=none] (C5-Start) -- (C5-End) coordinate[pos=0.7, label=](AC5);
\draw[->, very thick, red] (AC5) -- ($(AC5)!10mm!(C5-Start)$);

% OR
\def\wStart{-10}
\def\wEnd{88}
\def\R{0.75}
\draw[->, very thick, red] ([shift=(\wStart:\R)]OR-box.center)
   arc[start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, radius=\R];   

% OM
\path[draw=none] (El2) -- (Er2) coordinate[pos=0.5, label=](OM1);
\path[draw=none] (Dl2) -- (Dr2) coordinate[pos=0.5, label=](OM2);
\path[draw=none] ($(OM1)!0.2!(OM2)$) coordinate(OM3);
\draw[red,->, very thick] (OM3) -- ($(OM1)!10mm!(OM2)$);

%OF
\draw[red,->, very thick, shorten >=0.5mm, shorten <=6mm,
] ([yshift=3mm]OF.west) -- ([yshift=3mm]OF.east);
\draw[red,->, very thick, shorten >=3mm, shorten <=3mm,
] (OF.east) -- (OF.west);
% ===========================

%% CoSy
\begin{scope}[>=stealth, yshift=-0mm]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node [below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node [below] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node [pos=1.3] {$z$};
\end{scope}

% Tests
%\draw (MB-box.north east) -- (MB-box.south east);
%\draw (PC-box.east) circle(3mm); 
%\draw (PD2-box.north) circle(3mm); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Hint 2: Comment out
% Show Coordinates and Name - comment out! =======
\draw[dashdotted] (#6-start) -- (#6-end) node[midway, above]{#6};% Test
\draw[dotted] (#6-Start) -- (#6-End) node[]{};% Test

if you do not want to see the component names and their help lines.

+1 for the result even better than the original, having vectors in our documents is greatly appreciated.
